# Best method to route high current PCB with in a tight space constraint

Tags: power, pcb, pcb-design, ac

I was wondering if someone can give me advice in routing this PCB.

[image]

The PCB contains several triacs driving AC loads and digital end which contains a micro and several digital I/Os. So far, I have decided on the following:

- Use 18 AWG wire to connect the LIVE via the spade terminals.
- Use 5oz copper on the top layer to reduce the track width for the high current tracks for triac output to AC load spade terminal.
- Solder Y caps underneath the board with insulation and hot melt glue.
- Use 4 layers
- First layer contains AC tracks on the mains side and DC signal tracks on the digital side.
- Second layer contains ground layer on the digital side with some signals.
- Third layer contains digital VCC layer on the digital side with some signals.
- Fourth layer contains signals on digital and secondary voltage from the transformer.

I have few constraints in the design like the placements of the headers and AC spade terminals cannot be modified plus the board size cannot be changed. I have placed the heatsink/triacs and spade terminals so I can route the signal tracks to the optocouplers and secondary output of the transformer via the middle of the PCB. I am trying to ensure there is a least 2.5mm separation for the AC tracks.

Do anyone see any issues or problems with this layout or have any suggestions?

Regards
Paul

Comment: I am going to route the AC side on the bottom layer so I can route the digital side on the top layer.

Comment: How big these currents are? Actually I am not sure you need 4 layers in this PCB.

Comment: 15A 230V. The main reason why I chose four layers is to be able to route the optocouplers input/ground and secondary output of the transformer to the digital part of the circuit.

Comment: The dimension of the board is 240mm x 30mm as an additional information. I have routed the 4 layer board and asked the PCB manufacturer for a quote to see how much it will cost.

Comment: Related: This excellent reference - [**TI  Analog Engineer’s Pocket Reference - 4th edition**](https://www.ti.com/seclit/sl/slyw038b/slyw038b.pdf) provides some useful information on PCB track current/ voltage drop / heat / fusing issues. Especially pages 55-68.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 15A/230V you need 2mm track width and 2mm of clearances (5Oz/ft2 Cu and 20*C temperature rise).

Although, IMO, using 0.2mm copper PCB is pretty over engineered. The same results can be reached with more careful trace design.

Comment: You are probably right. Just by looking at the PCB, I notice I can shift one of my spade terminals and reducing the track length. I could also use both top and bottom layers to route the high current tracks.

Comment: Reduced it down to two layers. Just finding a way to supply the current.

Comment: Ok got it down to 2oz of copper and two layers now. This will be a significant drop in cost for the manufactured board.

Comment: @user468662 Good work. Now it sounds as a reasonable design. :)