# Proper way to route high-voltage tracks near THT components

Tags: pcb-design, isolation, creepage

I think this is not a duplicate of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85216/best-method-to-route-high-current-pcb-with-in-a-tight-space-constraint) question.
My design has the following constraints:

- type and position of connectors
- pinout assignments
- 260 VDC / 2A for high-voltage tracks
- 12V / 200 mA for low-voltage tracks

Here a part of my layout. It's repeated identically for every sector of the circular PCB:

[image: PCB]

Let's call the square pad of the connector pin 1:

- Pin 1 and 2: high-voltage tracks (260 VDC / 2A)
- Pin 3 and 4: low-voltage tracks (12V / 200 mA)
- pin 5 and 6: low-voltage (signals) tracks (5V / 1 mA)

The connector pitch is 3,5 mm in X and 3 mm in Y. They are Molex 172316-1206 and can withstand 400V / 11A.
For pins 3..6 I have no problems.

My concerns are about pins 1..2, in particular how to properly route the tracks between pin 2 and the middle pad above. I'm afraid about the isolation between bottom track (blue) and the nearby pads.

The track is 32 mil width (to maximise isolation) and the distance to the left and right pads (one is the capacitor, the other pin 1 of the connector) is 2.2 mm *from center-to-center*. The real creepage between the track and the outer ring of the pad is about 1 mm.

I checked [here](http://www.smps.us/pcbtracespacing.html) the needed spacing for 300 VDC isolation:

```
IPC-2221B:   
    external   1.25 mm
    internal   0.2 mm
    coated     0.4 mm
```

I'm not sure (even reading the description in the page) what does "coated" actually mean.

I'm working on a standard PCB with 2-layers and solder mask on both sides. I have to consider my tracks as "external" or "coated"?

Comment: Depends. Do you do conformal coating over the pins?

Comment: As said, it's a common PCB with solder mask but without any other treatment on pins.

Comment: Then you need to measure the creepage from pin to pin on top of your solar mask. What CTI does your soldermask have?

Comment: @winny why pin-to-pin? Aren't we talking about track-to-pin isolation?

Comment: About soldermask CTI: I cannot find this information on the website of my supplier (Eurocircuits). I'm going to ask them tomorrow if it's an important value to know.

Comment: It’s crucial! See andrea’s answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/326517/minimum-clearance-between-two-traces-that-have-a-potential-difference-of-1000vdc. You need to compute the creepage on top of your soldermask (with CTI value) pin-pin as well as under it (no CTI value required) for pin-track and track-track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't modify the PCB layout to provide the necessary clearance, you could coat the PCB after assembly with something like [Corona Dope](https://www.mgchemicals.com/products/insulating-coatings/super-corona-dope-4226) which has a high dielectric strength.

Comment: Most board manufactures use Polyurethane spray on both sides of the board. This covers most creapage issues. In cases where high-voltage (>400VAC) isolation is needed only slot cuts work.